# Assets doesn't compile (I include linker folder but doesn't work)

Tags: sails.js, assets

I created my project without linker flag because I didnt know that was important thing when you run production mode. Now, I created a linker and moved folders js, styles and templates.

First, my importer.less:

```
@import 'assets/styles/styles.less';
```

But now I changed:

```
@import 'assets/linker/styles/styles.less';
```

But doesn't work, both modes, developer and production.

Answer (score 0):

The linker folder is no longer necessary. The grunt tasks and pipeline configure which files are compiled and linked.

The import statement will be relative to your `importer.less` file. Assuming the `importer.less` file is in the same folder as the rest of your *less* files:

```
@import 'styles'; // styles.less
```

Look over your task runner configurations and try to understand them in `tasks/register/`, `tasks/config/`, and `tasks/pipeline.js`.